# Unable to insert data using POST request - Spring REST

Tags: spring-mvc, postman, spring-rest

I am making a simple project that uses a Spring RESTApi. I tried to insert data into database using POST request but unfortunately got error there. 
I am using Postman for API request.

All other request get, delete and put works fine but post doesn't work.

i have tried inserting data manually without using api but that works fine for me.

The error is;

[image: Error]

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> createUser(@RequestBody User user, UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder) {
        try {
            userService.insert(user);
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setLocation(ucBuilder.path("/user/{id}").buildAndExpand(user.getUserId()).toUri());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

**POSTMAN**
[image]

Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Have you been through the list that Postman is giving you to ensure it’s not any of those?

Comment: @DannyDainton - I tried all but didn't work. Later i found the solution after posting in another tab and the problem is solved. Thanks for your response